# Sphinx Rtd Theme override footer using Jinja

Tags: jinja2, python-sphinx

I am attempting to override the footer in the `Sphinx RTD theme` within a `Sphinx` based document and have not yet found a good way to do it. I have attempted to do this by supplying the following footer to `Sphinx`.

```
{% extends '!footer.html' %}
<footer>
      .
      .
      .
</footer>
```

When I do this, the contents of my `footer.html` file are ignored and the contents of `footer.html` in the base theme are displayed. I used the `!` character in the extends statement as a result of seeing it 
suggested in a post that I can no longer find. If I remove this, I get a Jinja error as follows when I attempt to build the `Sphinx` document:

```
Theme error:
An error happened in rendering the page Background.
Reason: RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison')
```

I want to completely replace the footer with my own. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: I think you're missing some `block` markup, too. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/templating.html

Comment: @Steve Piercy Unfortunately the underlying base footer.html does not provide blocks so there is nothing to override.

Comment: @Steve Piercy I am trying to replace the base footer.html, not override it.

Comment: Sounds like you need to fork the package and create your own footer.html.

Comment: @Steve Piercy That is not a feasible solution because I want the production version of the document to run on RTD so I need the solution to run without modifying RTD code.

Comment: I think you either need to look again at how Sphinx templating works (hint: extend laout.html), or fork the package and release your own and use that on RTD.